# Hide custom fields on @@personal-information view

Tags: plone

I'm following collective.examples.userdata to add some custom fields on the register form.

One field is the "accept terms", which the c.e.userdata also has and documents, and as said on the [package description](http://plone.org/products/collective.examples.userdata) (or at least I understood that way) the special "Accept Terms" field should only be shown on the registration form but not on the @@personal-information view.

I also tried adding c.e.userdata on my buildout with a fresh new Plone site and it's also shown on @@personal-information, so I'm wondering if it's a misunderstood from me or that there's a bug there.

Anyone knows how to show a field on the @@register form but hide it on @@personal-information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hiding a field from the `@@personal-information` form and only show it on the `@@register` form is not supported out-of-the-box, only the other way around.

You'll have to customize either the one or the other form to accomplish this; customize plone.app.users.browser.personalpreferences.UserDataPanel to remove your field or provide a new version of plone.app.users.browser.register.RegistrationForm to add your field there.

Here's how I'd do it:

```py
plone.app.users.browser.personalpreferences import UserDataPanel

class CustomizedUserDataPanel(UserDataPanel):
    def __init__(self, context, request):
        super(CustomizedUserDataPanel, self).__init__(context, request)
        self.form_fields = self.form_fields.omit('acceptTerms')
```

Note the `.omit('acceptTerms')`, I had to guess at the name of your extra field. You can then register this customized panel with ZCML against your theme browser layer, or directly on your Plone site or a custom interface. Here I take the easy way out and register it for the Plone site object:

```xml
<browser:page
    for="Products.CMFPlone.Portal.PloneSite"
    name="personal-information"
    class=".mymodule.CustomizedUserDataPanel"
    permission="cmf.SetOwnProperties"
    />
```

This should work for both Plone 4.0 and 4.1, as this particular class did not change.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly! Maybe it would make sense to update collective.examples.userdata to also do the same, since the docs say it.