# Hiding "personal preferences tab" in plone user preferencias

Tags: plone

Plone user preferences has 3 tabs: "Personal information", "Personal preferences" and "Password". I want to hide the "Personal preferences" tab because I don't want that the user changes/sees the fields contained within.

I tried this:

Hiding all the fields in the "Personal preferences" tab, as explained in "[Hide custom fields on @@personal-information view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174506/hide-custom-fields-on-personal-information-view)". But the tab still appears even it is empty.

Any other ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to go to zmi -> portal_actions -> preferences and uncheck "visible" and finally click save.

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS.

```
#personaltools-dashboard {display:none}
```

Or you can do it with diazo, but I've never played with diazo

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Auspex, for pointing me to the correct direction.

Finally, I achieved this including a diazo rule into the theme's rules.xml:

```
<drop css:content="#contentview-user_data-personal-preferences" />
```